# Check for strings inside list python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have

```
a = "FIFA 13"
```

then I writing

```
"bla" and "13" in a
```

And result is true... Why? **bla** is not in the a

Comment: What you mean is: `"bla" in a and "13" in a`

Comment: If programming was like speaking english, then the amount of bugs in a software would decrease significantly.

Comment: @Fred That's very, very debatable. English is highly ambiguous, an extremely undesirable attribute for programming languages.

Comment: @Fred - I think the opposite is infinitely more likely.  Spoken language, especially English, is _far_ too ambiguous.

Comment: and besides ... python is pretty dang close ;P

Comment: You did get it was a joke right? I mean... obviously he coded like he would speak, like "is 'bla' and '13' inside list a?"...

Comment: <3 python. - also, grr 15 characters.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"bla"` is **true**

`"13" in a` is **true**

Hence, `"bla" and "13" in a` is **true**

What you wanted to write is probably : `("bla" in a) and ("13" in a)`

Comment: You don't need parentheses here. The `in` operator has a higher precedence than the `and` operator. See: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#summary

Comment: I know, it's only for clarity since the person who asked is not familiar with that.

Answer (score 8):

Your boolean expression is being evaluated as `("bla") and ("13" in a)`, non-empty strings evaluate as true, so if `"13" in a` is true then the entire expression will evaluate as true.

Instead, use `all()`:

```
all(x in a for x in ("bla", "13"))
```

Or just check both separately:

```
"bla" in a and "13" in a
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
In [1]: a = "FIFA 13"

In [2]: "bla" in a and "13" in a
Out[2]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't interpreted like it is read:

```
("bla") and ("13" in a)
```

`"bla"` is truthy, so it automatically evaluates to `True`. `"13" in a` might be `True`. `False and True` evaluates to `True`, so `"bla"` isn't really taken into consideration.

You have to be a bit more explicit:

```
'bla' in a and '13' in a
```

Or you can use an unreadable one-liner:

```
all(map(a.__contains__, ('bla', '13')))
```

For a short-circuiting one-liner, I think you'll have to use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`..

Comment: we can also use `operator.contains()`, `all(map(lambda x:contains(a,x),("bla","12")))
`